# Delphi Android : I can not bind TMSFMXGrid to a BindSourceDB1

Tags: android, delphi, tms

I have setup a connection with UniConnection1 to a SQL Server. 
All the settings are right and a connection can be  established.
BindSourceDB1 is linked to my stored procedure which is set to execute after establishing a connection.

However I can not bind TMSFMXGrid to a BindSourceDB1. It wont accept it.

I tried using a DataSource.Linked it to UniStoredProc1 and used the Bindings wizzard (Link a grid with a DataSource). However TMSFMXGrid is not on the menu. I have TGrid,TStringGrid,TTMSFXLiveGrid...

I tried with the later. It just created another grid. However at this point
if I set the stored procedure to active I can see the data in the database.

When I run the application on my phone I can not edit anything (though it should be editable). My dbnavigator that came with the wizard is almost useless. I can only move through the records. So why is it taht I can not link my components (datasource) to the actual TMSFMXGrid?

Comment: What do TMS say about this problem?  You should ask them first before asking here ...

Comment: TMSFMXGrid does *not* support Live-Bindings after a specific version of the TMS FMX UI Pack. I can't check which version right now.

Comment: The problem with their particular grid is that it has no property by itself  with which you can bind it to a data-source. Maybe I am blind but I cant find it. It has LiveBindings but you cant connect. I think I will ask them what is going on here.

Comment: @user763539: which version of the FMX UI Pack do you use?

Comment: From the Change-Log in `TMSFMXPack.txt` for Version `3.4.8.5`: *Removed FMX.TMSGridDataBinding.pas unit, for LiveBindings please use TTMSFMXLiveGrid*